# TypeError: apply_gradients() got an unexpected keyword argument 'global_step'

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror, reinforcement-learning

After days trying to make one RL agent, I finally succeeded in creating its experience, but when I try to train it I get this error. I've tried all I could: different experience, changed step params... I am just out of ideas.

```py
import pyxinput
import time
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import keyboard
import tensorflow
import tf_agents
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import torch
#from tf_agents.networks import actor_distribution_networ

from tf_agents.policies import random_py_policy

Tensod_spec = tf_agents.specs.BoundedArraySpec(
   (15,),
   dtype=np.float32,
   name="XimputSpecs",
   minimum=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   maximum=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
)

Tensod_spec2 = tf_agents.specs.TensorSpec(
   [440, 600, 1], dtype=tf.int32, name="ScreenSpecs"
)

Tensor_reward_spe = tf_agents.specs.TensorSpec(
   [1, 1], dtype=tf.int32, name="Reward"
)

FromEnv = tf_agents.specs.BoundedTensorSpec(
   shape=(440, 600, 1),
   dtype='uint8',
   name='observation',
   minimum=0,
   maximum=255
)
FromEnv2 = tf_agents.specs.BoundedTensorSpec(
   shape=(1, 440, 600, 1),
   dtype=tf.int32,
   name='observation',
   minimum=0,
   maximum=255
)

fullscreen = [110, 130, 710, 570]

screenpil = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=fullscreen)
showprint = np.array(screenpil)
grayscreen = cv2.cvtColor(showprint, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
screenrect = cv2.cvtColor(grayscreen, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
grayscreen = grayscreen.reshape(440, 600, 1)

time_step_spec2 = tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.time_step_spec(
   observation_spec=FromEnv,
   #reward_spec = Tensor_reward_spec
)

time_step_spec = tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.time_step_spec(
    observation_spec=FromEnv,
    #reward_spec = Tensor_reward_spec
)

actor_net = tf_agents.networks.actor_distribution_network.ActorDistributionNetwork(
   input_tensor_spec=FromEnv,
   output_tensor_spec=tf_agents.specs.tensor_spec.from_spec(Tensod_spec),
   activation_fn='relu',
   #conv_layer_params=[(25, 40, 2)],
   fc_layer_params=(50, 25, 15),
   #dtype='int32'
)
print(actor_net)

train_step_counter = tf.dtypes.cast(1, tf.int32)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003)

tf_agent = tf_agents.agents.ReinforceAgent(
   time_step_spec=time_step_spec,
   action_spec=tf_agents.specs.tensor_spec.from_spec(Tensod_spec),
   actor_network=actor_net,
   optimizer=optimizer,
   normalize_returns=True,
   #train_step_counter=tf.Variable(1, name="global_step")
   )
tf_agent.initialize()

grayscreen2 = grayscreen
grayscreen2 = grayscreen2.reshape(1, 440, 600, 1)
time_step2 = tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.TimeStep(
   step_type=tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.StepType.FIRST,
   reward=tf.dtypes.cast(1, tf.float32),
   discount=tf.dtypes.cast(1, tf.float32),
   observation=grayscreen2
)

policy_state = tf_agent.policy.get_initial_state(batch_size=1)

policy_step = tf_agent.policy.action(time_step2, policy_state)
print(policy_step)

observe = time_step2.observation
#print(observe.dtype)
#observe = observe.astype(int)
#print(observe.shape)

experience = tf_agents.trajectories.trajectory.Trajectory(
   action=tf.compat.v2.Variable([
           tf.compat.v2.Variable(policy_step.action),
           tf.compat.v2.Variable(policy_step.action),
           tf.compat.v2.Variable(policy_step.action)
   ]),
   reward=tf.compat.v2.Variable([[
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(time_step2.reward),
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(time_step2.reward),
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(time_step2.reward)
   ]]),
   step_type=tf.compat.v2.Variable([[
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.StepType.FIRST),
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.StepType.MID),
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.StepType.LAST)
   ]]),
   observation=tf.compat.v2.Variable([
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(observe),
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(observe),
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(observe)
   ]),
   policy_info=tf_agent.policy.info_spec,
   next_step_type=tf.compat.v2.Variable([[
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.StepType.MID),
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.StepType.LAST),
       tf.compat.v2.Variable(tf_agents.trajectories.time_step.StepType.LAST)
   ]]),
   discount=tf.compat.v2.Variable([[
       tf.dtypes.cast(1, tf.float32),
       tf.dtypes.cast(1, tf.float32),
       tf.dtypes.cast(1, tf.float32)
   ]]), 
)

train_loss = tf_agent.train(experience)
print(train_loss)
```

And I get this error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4dd3966a32b6> in <module>
      1 #
----> 2 train_loss = tf_agent.train(experience)
      3 print(train_loss)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\agents\tf_agent.py in train(self, experience, weights, **kwargs)
    516 
    517     if self._enable_functions:
--> 518       loss_info = self._train_fn(
    519           experience=experience, weights=weights, **kwargs)
    520     else:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\utils\common.py in with_check_resource_vars(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
    183         # We're either in eager mode or in tf.function mode (no in-between); so
    184         # autodep-like behavior is already expected of fn.
--> 185         return fn(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
    186       if not resource_variables_enabled():
    187         raise RuntimeError(MISSING_RESOURCE_VARIABLES_ERROR)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\agents\reinforce\reinforce_agent.py in _train(self, experience, weights)
    286                                           self.train_step_counter)
    287 
--> 288     self._optimizer.apply_gradients(
    289         grads_and_vars, global_step=0)
    290 

TypeError: apply_gradients() got an unexpected keyword argument 'global_step'
```

What is this global step, and where is this error coming from? Why can't I train my agent?

Specs:

- Python 3.8
- TensorFlow 2.4 (GPU and non-GPU)
- Windows 10 / ubuntu

If you need more info, please let me know.

EDIT: Tried other agents they run fine and i posted this ISUE on Tensor
GIT:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48424
If anyone has the same problem in the future

Comment: Can you post your solution under answer section for the benefit of community.Thanks!

Comment: To reiterate what TFer2 said... Questions should be questions, and answers should be answers. What you added as an edit should really be an answer. Please remove it from your question and post it as an answer. You can even accept your own answer.

Comment: Followed the issue link but the question isn't resolved there at all (although it's marked as resolved by the author him/herself, again).

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use a different Optimizer. Those in `tf.keras.optimizer` don't take `global_steps` as an argument in `apply_gradients` function.
Instead, use these from `tf.compat.v1.train`, e.g.,

```
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate=0.003)
```

Note this passes the runtime check, but it makes the training impossible to complete. `global_step` is supposed to take a `Variable` and its value will be `+1` when `apply_gradients` is called. However, here you see `global_step=0` is passed in making it no effect at all. The `train_step_counter` you defined above will remain `0`.

Also note there's a [fix](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/commit/266251e43c34cce541fd80442e754d6a092aa74f) on the way.